# Android proguard with volley: ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.volley.VolleyLog"

Tags: java, android, android-volley, proguard

I'm creating a library project in Android.
I want to enable pro-guard but I get the following crash:

```
Process: com.mysdk.myapplication, PID: 15629
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/volley/VolleyLog;
    at com.mysdk.sdk.api.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysdk.sdk.api.mysdk.startmysdk(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysdk.myapplication.App.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1026)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5099)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1464)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:819)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:709)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.volley.VolleyLog" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mysdk.myapplication-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mysdk.myapplication-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at com.mysdk.sdk.api.b.a(Unknown Source) 
    at com.mysdk.sdk.api.mysdk.startmysdk(Unknown Source) 
    at com.mysdk.myapplication.App.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1026) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5099) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:150) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1464) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:819) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:709) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.volley.VolleyLog
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

In my library project I have a proguard-rules.pro file configured with the following:

```
-keep class com.android.volley.** { *; }
-keep interface com.android.volley.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.android.volley.VolleyLog { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.** { *; }
```

I found some solutions on the web (such as adding the apache line to my pro-guard file) but it didn't work.
Any suggestions? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The instruction

```
-keepclassmembers class com.android.volley.VolleyLog { *; }
```

tells ProGuard to keep the class members (methods, fields, etc) but still lets it obfuscate the name of the actual class, meaning that it can be renamed to something like "a.a.b.a" in the APK.

Use a tool like [ClassyShark](https://github.com/google/android-classyshark) to check if `com.android.volley.VolleyLog` is being included in the APK and if not, then change the rule to:

```
-keep class com.android.volley.VolleyLog { *; }
```

to make ProGuard preserve the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly Instant Run feature of Android Studio creating such problems with different Class names some time MainApplication Class not found...
i also faced these issues many times but neither Clean,Rebuild solved my problem nor Multidex steps Solved my problem but when i turned OFF instant Run then my app started working normally instead of this runtime crash or Crash on Start of app

Just do this..
check File-->Setting -->Build,Execution,Deployment-->Instant Run 
and Enable it if its Turned OFF or Disable it If its Turned ON